# Running django application on port 80 using nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a Django+nginx+uwsgi stack set up on my Production server and I'm trying to get it to run on port 80. To test my Django app, I tried manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 but it gave me a permissions issue. I attempted to sudo the command but django is only installed on my virtualenv so it ran into issues. I can hit my server on port 80 through a browser and it has the default nginx splash page. Here are my config files:

nginx.conf

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on and the domain name it will serve for
    listen      8000;
    server_name ip-address-here; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQD

    root /home/user1;
    access_log /home/user1/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/user1/logs/error.log;
    charset     utf-8;

    gzip on;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media/  {
        alias /home/user1/Project/static/img/;  # your Django project's media files - ame$
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/user1/Project/static/; # your Django project's static files - amend a$
    }

    location /img/ {
        autoindex on;
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8889;
        include     uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
# variables
projectname = Project
projectdomain = project.com
base = /home/user1

# config
master = true
protocol = uwsgi
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(projectname).settings
pythonpath = %(base)/%(projectname)
module = %(projectname).wsgi:application
socket = 127.0.0.1:8889
logto = %(base)/logs/uwsgi.log

#below line runs it as a daemon in background
daemonize = /home/user1/logs/project_uwsgi.log
```

Also, when it comes to running a stack like this, what kind of users should I have set up? Ie. What user should I run nginx as? What user should I set up my project under? Currently, I have my project set up under the /home/user1 directory, and I'm running nginx as user1. I also use user1 to ssh into my machine. I have disabled the root account for security purposes, but user1 has sudo privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nginx serving on port 8000, but it should be 80.

If you installed it through your distribution's package manager, it should set up the users for you.

Comment: Yes. But changing the user is not the solution to serving static files.